# Can user specify Vault's policies while creating his token from github?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

So currently learning Vault by Hashicorp and I am trying to understand the concept of authentication using GitHub Tokens. While creating a token in GitHub, one can specify policies to that token and I was wondering if those have any effect on Vault's policies assigned to that user since operator create policies and map them at the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: // , Thanks for phrasing this in the form of a question, @Badr. You might also want to try cross posting this here for a faster response: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vault-tool Can you give us an example of the code that does this

Answer (score 1):

When you create a GitHub user on Vault, you can assign to him a Vault policy. That policy is the only one that is assigned to that user, and GitHub policies are the same of the Vault ones. The full procedure is:

- Create a GitHub user in Vault
- Assign him a Vault policy, previously written.
- The user authenticate in Vault and got a token with the policy assigned.

The GitHub users are separated from the default Vault users, so if you assigne a Vault policy to a GitHub user it has no effect to other Vault users.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean though that anyone can then create Github account and get Token with MAX policies available and of course this is not logical. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you create a new GitHub account this needs to be mapped to a Vault policy. I don't know what happens if don't map a policy, but I think that it won't allow login or it return a default policy to that user. I got your point now?

Comment: I am aware of that. I mean what I do understand is that adding policies while creating the token (On GitHub) is doubted to have any effect at all.

Comment: I think that Vault policies are not associated with GitHub policies

Comment: I believe so as well.